# S3 website with access restricted to VPC endpoint is getting 403 from inside the VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

I would like to create an S3 bucket that is configured to work as a website, and I would like to **restrict access to the S3 website to requests coming from inside a particular VPC** only.

I am using Cloudformation to set up the bucket and the bucket policy.

The bucket CF has the `WebsiteConfiguration` enabled and has `AccessControl` set to `PublicRead`.

```
  ContentStorageBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties: 
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      BucketName: "bucket-name"
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        IndexDocument: index.html
        ErrorDocument: error.html
```

The bucket policy includes two conditions: one condition grants access full access to the bucket when on the office IP, and the other condition grants access through a VPC endpoint. The code is as follows:

```
  ContentStorageBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref ContentStorageBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: BucketPolicy
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Sid: FullAccessFromParticularIP
          Action:
          - s3:*
          Effect: "Allow"
          Resource:
          - !GetAtt [ ContentStorageBucket, Arn ]
          - Fn::Join:
            - '/'
            - - !GetAtt [ ContentStorageBucket, Arn ]
              - '*'
          Principal: "*"
          Condition:
            IpAddress:
              aws:SourceIp: "x.x.x.x"
        - Sid: FullAccessFromInsideVpcEndpoint
          Action:
          - s3:*
          Effect: "Allow"
          Resource:
          - !GetAtt [ ContentStorageBucket, Arn ]
          - Fn::Join:
            - '/'
            - - !GetAtt [ ContentStorageBucket, Arn ]
              - '*'
          Principal: "*"
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              aws:sourceVpce: "vpce-xxxx"
```

To test the above policy conditions, I have done the following:

- I've added a file called `json.json` to the S3 bucket;
- I've created an EC2 instance and placed it inside the VPC referenced in the bucket.
- I've made a curl request to the file endpoint `http://bucket-name.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/json.json` **from inside the whitelisted IP address, and the request succeeds**;
- I've made a curl request to the file endpoint **from inside the EC2 instance (placed in the VPC), and the request fails with a 403 Access Denied**

Notes:

- I have made sure that the EC2 instance is in the correct VPC.
- The `aws:sourceVpce` is not using the value of the VPC ID, but it is using the value of the Endpoint ID of the corresponding VPC.
- I have also used `aws:sourceVpc` with the VPC ID, instead of using the `aws:sourceVpce` with the endpoint ID, but this produced the same results as the one mentioned above.

Given this, I currently am not sure how to proceed in further debugging this. Do you have any suggestions about what might be the problem? Please let me know if the question is not clear or anything needs clarification. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you checked the route table for the subnet that your EC2 instance is in? You'll need a route for the prefix list representing S3 endpoints to the vpc endpoint (there will be a route saying pl-XXXXXXXX to vpce-XXXXXXXX). If this route isn't there, your request will go over the public Internet  and be denied unless it's on the whitelisted IP.

Comment: Sounds like a great use-case for the brand new [Managing Data Access with Amazon S3 Access Points](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-points.html).

Comment: Does access work if you use IAM creds via the awscli rather than no creds and curl? Also, possible debugging help: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-s3-vpc-endpoint/

Comment: @TopherIsSwell thank you for flagging this. Currently I do not have that route in the route table, so this might very well be the problem. I will look into this and report back if it worker. Thank you for your help. Also thanks to jarmod for mentioning the debugging link that also seems to point me to the missing route.

Comment: @RafaelMarques your bucket policy worked for me without any changes, so its obviously the routes or the VPC endpoint policy.

Comment: Just wondering, how we would enable SSL for the static private website, if i point site.mydomain.com to the s3 static website host name, it wont obviously work because the s3 static website url is `HTTP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for resources to use the VPC endpoint for S3, the VPC router must point all traffic destined for S3 to the VPC endpoint. Rather than maintain a list of all of the CIDR blocks that are S3 specific on your own, AWS allows you to use BGP prefix lists which are a first-class resource in AWS.

To find the prefix list for S3 run the following command (your output should match mine, since this should be the same region wide across all accounts, but best to check). Use the region of your VPC.

```sh
aws ec2 describe-prefix-lists --region us-east-1
```

I get the following output:

```js
{
    "PrefixLists": [
        {
            "Cidrs": [
                "54.231.0.0/17",
                "52.216.0.0/15"
            ],
            "PrefixListId": "pl-63a5400a",
            "PrefixListName": "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3"
        },
        {
            "Cidrs": [
                "52.94.0.0/22",
                "52.119.224.0/20"
            ],
            "PrefixListId": "pl-02cd2c6b",
            "PrefixListName": "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.dynamodb"
        }
    ]
}
```

For com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3, the prefix list id is pl-63a5400a,

so you can then create a route in whichever route table services the subnet in question. The Destination should be the prefix list (pl-63a5400a), and the target should be the VPC endpoint ID (vpce-XXXXXXXX) (which you can find with a `aws ec2 describe-vpc-endpoints`).

This is trivial from the console. I don't remember how to do this from the command line, I think you have to send a cli-input-json with something like the below, but I haven't tested. this is left as an exercise for the reader.

```js
{
  "DestinationPrefixListId": "pl-63a5400a",
  "GatewayId": "vpce-12345678",
  "RouteTableid": "rt-90123456"
}
```

Comment: I believe this is a quite useful answer and I will test it out. 
I have one question though: should the route be set on the route table of the VPC, or on the route table of the subnet in which the EC2 instance is set.
Thanks! @TopherIsSwell

Comment: This answer is correct and pointed me in the right direction.
I was able to add the subnet(s) route table(s) to the VPC endpoint, and with the bucket policy set to allow this endpoint, the requests now succeed.

Comment: Okay, good to hear. For clarification to anyone else reading this, the VPC will have a main/default route table that applies to all subnets that don't have an assigned route table. So I'm referring to either the route table explicitly assigned to the subnet, or the main VPC route table if no other route table applies. If you find this answer helpful, it would help me and others with this problem if you mark it as accepted. Thanks and good luck!